# Setup Library and Include Folders Permanently

Tags: visual-studio

I often need to use OpenCV and C++ for my projects. To setup libraries for OpenCV what I do each time for every individual project is this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

And after the last window above add names like:

```
opencv_calib3d245d.lib
opencv_contrib245d.lib
opencv_core245d.lib...
```

However doing this for every project is somewhat timetaking and boring. Is it possible to setup Visual Studio 2015 once and for all to persist these settings for any Console App project I create?

Thanks.

[Image Source](http://opencv-srf.blogspot.de/2013/05/installing-configuring-opencv-with-vs.html)

Comment: Well, with recent opencv versions you can also use only opencv_worldXXX.lib. (btw, upgrade to a recent version... 2.4.5 is quite old). You can also make your own property sheet with links to opencv in visual studio, and add it to your new projects